# Get Column Name By Hibernate Query

Tags: hibernate

```
Query query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);       
query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer());

List results = query.list();
```

In above code, `results` contains elements of Map and I am able to get the column name by  key of Map but as you know `query.list()` returns the elements of HashMap thats why the ordering of column name not in sequence and I want the column name odering baseed on sql-query sequence.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but it is a bit vexing as to why there isn't something like this in the transformers already.

Running the query with the transformer:

```
Query sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sqlStatement);
sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);

List results = query.list();
```

For the transformer, I extended BasicTransformerAdapter as opposed to AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.

```
import org.hibernate.transform.BasicTransformerAdapter

public class AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer extends BasicTransformerAdapter implements Serializable {
    public static final AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer INSTANCE = new AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer();

    private AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer() {

    }

    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        Map result = new LinkedHashMap(tuple.length)
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
            String alias = aliases[i]
            if (alias != null) {
                result.put(alias, tuple[i])
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private Object readResolve() {
        return INSTANCE
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return other != null && AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer.class.isInstance(other)
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().getName().hashCode()
    }
}
```

Nothing revolutionary or straightforward, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own `AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer`, by using the code of `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer` as an example, but using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap`. `LinkedHashMap` preserves insertion order.

Comment: How would i implement  own AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer

Comment: Take the source code of AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer, change the package and class names, and use a LinkedHashMap instead of a HashMap.

Comment: class AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer extends AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer { public Object TransformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {Map result = new LinkedHashMap(tuple.length); for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) { String alias = aliases[i]; if (alias != null) { result.put(aliases[i], tuple[i]);} } return result;} public List TransformList(List collection) { return collection; } } i have created this class and called its object as query.setResultTransformer(new AliasToEntityLinkedMapResultTransformer()); but same problem exists

Comment: Show us the query, add traces to show what the tuple and aliases array contain, and show us the result of those traces.

Comment: @JBNizet why would we need a LinkedHashMap or the order in column|value pairs? Sorry if it sounds dumb but I am not able to figure it out why.